# How do I leverage TDD to remove parts of the public facing API of a class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I have a class like so

```
public class Foo : ICompletable
{
    public IAmCompleted { get; set;} // from interface
   private IFooCollab collab;

  public Foo(IFooCollab collab)
{
  this.collab = collab;

}

 public YouCompleteMe()
{
  this.collab.command();
 this. IAmCompleted = true;

}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
public void when_i_am_completed_then_completed_is_true()
{
  var   sut = new Foo(new mock<IFooColab>().object);
  Assert.That(sut.IsCompleted, Is.True);
}


[Test]
public void  when_i_am_completed_command_is_issued()
{
 var collabMock = new mock<IFooCollab>();
 ...sut blah
   collabMock.verify(x => x.command(), Times.Once)
}
}
```

Removing the interface and anything using it l  is all I need to do.  How do I drive that from tests,  should I even.  If I delete test, functionality is still there. Id almost say do the opposite, break the test by breaking prod code :) grd.. green red delete

Comment: On bus on phone someone please format for mr.

Comment: i was wondering why public was Public ;)

Comment: I'm no expert on TDD, but could you not test using reflection that the interface no longer exists that you are supposed to remove?

Comment: That would be a way.  But probably not worth the effort.   I guess everything with TDD is geared toward driving out design and refactoring, but not really redesigning.  Arguably I could kill my implementation and start from scratch.  That does seem a bit wasteful though.

Comment: So the question really should be: `Do i want to ensure that by removing the interface the behaviour of depdendent classes does not change?` or `Should i remove the interface and all dependent classes and descendants?`. Specifically, if you want to do the first, you need to first refactor all tests to call methods directly without typecasting to interfaces, and then ensure that they all pass once you're done removing said interface. If you want to go the second route, simply delete the interface, implementations, dependents and unit tests.

Comment: @zaitsman - you are right it's a terribly worded question. I should rephrase it!

Comment: The way it is reworded it absolutely doesn't matter from the outcome perspective. You would delete it all -tests, classes, interfaces. In your commit there will be no tests that are failing. Unless, of course, you somehow believe that committing code that doesn't compile is okay for whatever reason.

Comment: I dont believe in committing code that doesnt compile, you may have misread my comments the other day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing unused code is part of the refactoring step.  If the code is truly not required, you can remove it and run the existing tests and everything should pass.

Comment: Just to clarify there are tests making asserts on that IAmCompleted property  Should I change the interface first and then correct the failing tests? By removing them?

Comment: To be strict, you should change or delete the tests first because they no longer describe your requirements correctly.  But it might be easier to let the computer find the incorrect tests for you by running them and seeing what fails.

Comment: I guess its a matter of preference? This can become quite religious.  One of the harder things i find is defending my decision to persue a certain approach. Even if, logically, it makes sense and the outcome is the same....

Comment: Doing what makes sense is important. TDD is a tool not a religion.  You always have to think about how to use it most effectively, not apply it blindly.